# How to fix "InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression" issue?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, ui-automation, browser-automation

[image]I am trying to automate a webpage using Selenium and Python. I have used 'xpath checker - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/' in firefox and written the following code.

Selenium-Python Code:

```
def create_user():

    #Click 'Administration'
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id('main-navigation')/x:li[5]/x:a").click()    
    mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id('main-navigation')/x:li[5]/x:ul/x:li[1]/x:ul[2]/x:li[2]/x:a").click()   
    mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id('accordion')/x:li[2]/x:a").click()  
    mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


create_user()
```

If I execute the above, I am getting following error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector //*[@id('main-navigation')
/x:li[5]/x:a is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following
 error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[
@id('main-navigation')/x:li[5]/x:a because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///c:/users/admin/appda
ta/local/temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-c
omponent.js:10744)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/admin/appd
ata/local/temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-
component.js:10775)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/admin/appdata/local
/temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component
.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/admin/appda
ta/local/temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-
processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/admin/appdata
/local/temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-pr
ocessor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/admin/appdata/local/
temp/2/tmpgchoem/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor
.js:12608)
```

Could anyone please suggest some idea to fix this code.

Comment: Why are you using `x:`....and it's `@id='main-navigation'` insteadof `@id('main-navigation')`...

Answer (score 0):

You need extra `]` to close `[@id=...]` block. So try

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-navigation']/x:li[5]/x:a").click()    
mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-navigation']/x:li[5]/x:ul/x:li[1]/x:ul[2]/x:li[2]/x:a").click()   
mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accordion']/x:li[2]/x:a").click()  
mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the above code. But still I am getting the same error : InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector //*[@id('main-navigation')
]/x:li[5]/x:a is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The followin
g error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[
@id('main-navigation')]/x:li[5]/x:a because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///c:/users/admin ....

Comment: you still use incorrect `XPath`. Check my answer one more time: I use `@id='main-navigation'` , but not `@id('main-navigation')`!

Comment: Also provide `HTML` code so I can check corectness. I'm not sure that `x:li` is correct expression

Comment: I have tried '@id='main-navigation'. But still same issue. I have added screenshot of source code in my question.

Comment: Try `mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data_item_id='administration']").click() ` for the first element. I can't see `HTML` on provided screen for rest elements

Comment: Apologize for the trouble. With the above code, I am getting following error: NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","se
lector":"//a[@data_item_id='administration']"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/admin/appd
ata/local/temp/2/tmpncivyo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-
component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/admin/appdata/local
/temp/2/tmpncivyo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component
.js:10779).

Comment: Is this because this webpage is using 'flash player' to run? Can't we use selenium to automate web pages that using flash player? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Check and let me know whether your elements located inside an `iframe/frame` block. Also try to replace `implicit` with `explicit` wait: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits